# How do I calculate and output punctuation marks using ispunct() for an input file

Tags: c++, file-io

I have a text file with a huge paragraph and I wanna be able to count and output all the punctuation marks in my file.. here is my code so far, it just prints "0"
Thanks.

```
int main(){
inFile.open("Horoscope.txt");
if (!inFile)
{
    cerr << "Error: Input file opening failed\n";
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}

int punct = 0;
char input = ' ';
while (inFile >> input)
{
    if (ispunct(input))
    {
        punct++;
    }
    inFile.close();
    cout << "There are " << punct << " punctuation marks in the text file" 
<< endl; 
}
}
```

Comment: This program doesn't even compile. Try again...!

Comment: Also, read some documentation (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/ispunct) particularly the note about using `char` with `ispunct` (as you are doing)

Comment: Yes it does, im doing multiple things as find vowels etc all in int main(), this is just the snippet for finding punc marks

Comment: [Nope, totally does not](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/956affebe140974e). At the very least, you have randomly removed one `}` from your algorithm before posting. If there is more code that you are not showing us, then this is not your [MCVE].

Comment: There are 1088 vowels in the text file, 
There are 2356 consonants in the text file, 
There are 0 punctuation marks in the text file, thats my output so far...and it keeps outputing 0 for punc

Comment: For a minimal example consider using and `istringstream` for `inFile`, with text specified in the code. That makes it reproducible. For now voting to close as lacking a reproducible example.

Comment: Nothing you have posted counts vowels or consonants. Post your [MCVE]. We will not debug code-that-is-like-this-code-but-not-exactly-but-the-problem-is-not-in-the-hidden-secret-code-honest

Comment: Someone posted the solution below, all I was looking for.

Comment: So you're _not_ going to read the documentation and the warning that how you're using `ispunct` is wrong? Okay.

Answer (score 0):

From what you have posted, it looks like you are closing the file in the loop, thus stopping the search.

Close the file once you are done with it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main() {
    std::ifstream inFile;
    inFile.open("Horoscope.txt");
    if (!inFile)
    {
        std::cerr << "Error: Input file opening failed\n";
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    int punct = 0;
    char input = ' ';
    while (inFile >> input)
    {
        if (ispunct(input))
        {
            punct++;
        }   
    }
    inFile.close();
    std::cout << "There are " << punct << " punctuation marks in the text file" << std::endl;
}
```